# Rails 5 action cable not working on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5

Im working with Rails 5 and integrate Action cable for chat system, its working fine on local, also working fine in production mode but not working on AWS elastic Beanstalk, please help me to resolve this problem, many thanks.

Following errors has coming:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://dreamermade-staging.qdmpcqqmnw.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404